# Why can't I use conio.h or ncurses.h?

Tags: compiling, programming, c, ncurses

I am new user to Ubuntu. I wrote a simple program in C. When I try to compile it to use `conio.h`, the compiler gives me fatal error. So I tried by ncurses.h, but still I am getting same error.

Comment: `conio.h` is not present in Linux. You need to use `curses` or `ncurses`. But if you are getting error like`fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory'`, it means this library is not installed.

Comment: Close voters: This most certainly is about using Ubuntu! It is programming related, but not in the sense that would make it off-topic (check the answer below).

Comment: amol , could you please take some time to review the below answer. Then accept it if that what you were looking for. See http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I find it amusing that `conio` is a curse word in spanish (afaik)

Answer (score 5):

#### Why `conio.h` Isn't Available

[g_p](https://askubuntu.com/users/146791/g-p) mostly answered this [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529114/fatal-error-occurs-for-conio-h-and-ncurses-h-while-compiling-c-program#comment721818_529114):

> `conio.h` is not present in Linux. You need to use `curses` or `ncurses`. But if you are getting error like`fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory'`, it means this library is not installed.

For more information on conio.h (and how it's DOS/Windows specific), see [the Wikipedia article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h).

#### Why `ncurses.h` Wasn't Available, and How To Fix It

As for ncurses, it's necessary to install the [libncurses5-dev [image: Install libncurses5-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libncurses5-dev) (or [libncursesw5-dev [image: Install libncursesw5-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libncursesw5-dev)) package, and then pass the `-lncurses` argument to `gcc` when compiling, for example:

```
gcc -Wall -g -o hello hello.c -lncurses
```

See [How do I create simplistic window-like elements in a command-line program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516344/how-do-i-create-simplistic-window-like-elements-in-a-command-line-program) (and *its* sources) for more information.